# Filter duplicated objects in array and filter by two properties

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I'm trying to filter or remove some duplicated objects from an array of objects. Here is what I have.

```
var itemsToFilter = [];
var filteredItems = [];
var items = [];

function filterRepeated (data) {

  _.forEach(data, function(e) {
    if(e.readingTime) {
      itemsToFilter.push(e);
    } else {
      items.push(e);
    }
  });

  filteredItems = _.uniq(itemsToFilter, 'id');
  items.push.apply(items, filteredItems);

  return items;
}
```

What I do with this function is to separate some objects if they have the property readingTime. The array itemsToFilter contains the objects that are repeated, i was trying to filter by id and readingTime with something like this.

```
var a = itemsToFilter.filter(function(n) {
    console.log(n);
    if(n['id'].indexOf() !== -1 && n['readingTime'].indexOf() !== -1) {
      console.log(n);
      //return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  });
```

But it does nothing.

The format of the objects I'm trying to filter:

```
 [{time: 1450672782667, sequence_number: 55240001, readingTime: 1450669920000, id: "56572093c007a1164a02a78c", tipo: "Posición actualizada"}, {time: 1450672782667, sequence_number: 55240001, readingTime: 1450669920000, id: "56572093c007a1164a02a78c", tipo: "Posición actualizada"}]
```

Thanks.

Comment: can you see any error in console?

Comment: No just return an empty array.

Comment: Your question is unclear. What exactly are you trying to do here. Are trying to filter duplicated objects, or filter objects which have a prop of `readingTime`, or are you trying to filter objects which have the same value for `readingTime` ? In your example the array contains only one object, with `readingTime` defined twice. Please explain, thanks.

Comment: Sorry I misspelled the object, what I'm trying to do is filter duplicated objects, by two properties, id and readingTime. I edited the array.

Comment: `n['id'].indexOf()` I think indexOf is missing a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

```
       var arr = []; 
       var a = itemsToFilter.filter(function(n) {
        console.log(n);
        if(arr.indexOf(n['id']) !== -1 && arr.indexOf(n['readingTime']) !== -1) {

          return true;
        } else {
 arr.push(n['id']);
          arr.push(n['readingTime']);
          return false;
        }
      });
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I've tried your code but still gives me an empty array, I know I'm missing something.

Comment: zahreelay, is there a way to filter entire objects, not create a new object with id and readingTime, I don't know if I was clear in my first post. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: what I'm missing, the filter you post still push all objects to the arr array.